# jQuery $('form').serialize() returns only one element of a form serialized

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following form:

```
<form id="form" name="form">
<input name="name"/>
<input name="version"/>
<input name="template"/>
<textarea name="elements"></textarea>
<textarea name="features"></textarea>
<textarea name="layout"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

and javascript (using jQuery 1.3.2):

```
$(function() {
    $('#form').bind('submit',function() { alert($('#form').serialize()); return false; });
    });
```

The output of submitting the above form from the above javascript alert is:

```
elements=...
```

Where ... is whatever is contained in the elements field.

I would expect that $('#form').serialize() to return a string something like:

```
name=&version=&template=&elements=&features=&layout=.
```

I do note that $('input,textarea').serialize() **does** perform the expected behaviour (i.e. return "name=&version=&template=&elements=asdafe&features=&layout="), however I'm curious as to why the $('#form') version only returns "elements=".

I've tried this on Safari 4 and Firefox 3.5, so I'm confident it's something I'm missing.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Try adding a name to your form.

Comment: @Zed: Thanks; unfortunately, adding a name didn't fix it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the name of your textarea that's throwing it off.

Here's how it breaks down.  In the DOM, `form` nodes have several special properties, most notably these two (which are exposed in this order)

1. The `elements` collections, which is an [HTMLCollection](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-DOM-Level-2-20000510/html.html#ID-75708506) of all the form controls (and a few other nodes like `<fieldset>` elements)
2. A property of each named element in the form (i.e., form controls that have a `name` attribute)

Since you have a `<textarea>` with the name "elements", this effectively overwrites the built-in `elements` collection mentioned in #1 above, which is why when you serialize the form all you see is

```
elements=****
```

Because that single form element has overwritten the entire collection.

Short solution?  re-name your form elements to values that aren't existing DOM properties (your `<input name="name"/>` falls into this category as well)

Comment: I've opened the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295851/what-are-valid-invalid-names-for-html-form-tags

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else stumbles on this problem, I had set the `disabled` property on all inputs before calling `serialize()`, so they weren't included in the set. Removing `disabled` before calling `serialize()` fixes this.

Answer (score -2):

The `.serializeArray()` method creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements. The form elements can be of several types: